# По каким причинам не стоит располагать блочный элемент внутри строчного?

Tags: html, css, dom, семантика

Знаю, что это плохо со стороны семантики и валидации.

Но может быть есть еще причины, указывающие на то, что так делать не надо?

Comment: можно только работать не будет ..

Comment: как и любая задача про впихнуть невпихуемое она просто не работает

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. Хотелось узнать, почему не стоит так делать.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что с некоторых пор пихать `<div>` внутрь `<a>` [вполне валидно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Блоки начинают вести себя необычно, например, идут два `span`, вроде бы строчные элементы, должны идти в строчку, но они идут не в строчку. Потому что `div` это блок и он начинает занимать всю доступную ширину на линии

```html
<span>Это текст</span>
<span><div>Это блок</div></span>
```

Comment: а что в этом необычного? делаю так для соответствующего эффекта

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я думаю, для новичков, которые начали изучать html, это необычно